# How to subtract two partial columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I'm just getting started with Pandas so I may be missing something important, but I can't seem to successfully subtract two columns I'm working with. I have a spreadsheet in excel that I imported as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/path/to/file.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1')
```

My table when doing `df.head()` looks similar to the following:

```
      a         b        c        d
0     stuff     stuff    stuff    stuff
1     stuff     stuff    stuff    stuff
2     data      data     data     data
...   ...       ...      ...      ...
89    data      data     data     data
```

I don't care about the "stuff;" I would like to subtract two columns of just the data and make this its own column. Therefore, it seemed obvious that I should trim off the rows I'm not interested in and work with what remains, so I have tried the following:

```
dataCol1 = df.ix[2:,0:1]
dataCol2 = df.ix[2:,1:2]
print(dataCol1.sub(dataCol2,axis=0))
```

But it results in

```
             a          b
2           NaN        NaN
3           NaN        NaN
4           NaN        NaN
...         ...        ...
89          NaN        NaN
```

I get the same result if I also simply try `print(dataCol1-dataCol2)`. I really don't understand how both of these subtraction operations not only result in all NaN's, but also two columns instead of just one with the end result. Because when I `print(dataCol1)`, for example, I do obtain the column I want to work with:

```
      a      
2     data     
3     data   
4     data     
...   ...
89    data
```

Is there any way to both work simply and directly from an Excel spreadsheet and perform basic operations with a truncated portion of the columns of said spreadsheet? Maybe there is a better way to go about this than using `df.ix` and I am definitely open to those methods as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the misallignment of your indices.

One thing to do would be to subtract the values, so you don't have to deal with alignment issues:

```
dataCol1 = df.iloc[2: , 0:1]   # ix is deprecated
dataCol2 = df.iloc[2: , 1:2]

result = pd.DataFrame(dataCol1.values - dataCol2.values)
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is `ix` deprecated though?

Comment: @Oak `ix` makes some assumptions about your data, and is a little more unstable. They decided to split its functionality into `loc` and `iloc`. Update your pandas and check it out.